# When using swipe in the Vue Composition API, how do I get the index when swiping?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, swipe

I am now getting the swiped index like this:

```js
const updateCurrentSlide = (e: any) => {
  currentSlide.value = slides.value[e.activeIndex];
};
..
 <swiper
      @slideChange="updateCurrentSlide"
    >
```

However, when autoplaying, the index does not change,
Also, when you move the slide with the mouse, the index changes too sensitively.
For example, when I swipe, I expected the index to change sequentially like 0, 1, 2, but it also changes like this: 0, 2, 2, 2, 1. What should I do?

Comment: It's not nearly enough code to reproduce or understand the issue.  Please review [how to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question to provide all relevant code.